# Retrain Frozen Graph in Tensorflow 2.x

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have managed this implementation on retraining frozen graph in tensorflow 1 according to [this wonderful detail topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53085007/re-train-a-frozen-pb-model-in-tensorflow). Basically, the methodology is described:

1. Load frozen model
2. Replace the `constant frozen node` with `variable node`.
3. The newly replaced variable node then will be redirected to the corresponding output of the frozen node.

This works in tensorflow 1.x by checking the `tf.compat.v1.trainable_variables`. However, in tensorflow 2.x, it can't work anymore.

Below is the code snippet:

1/ Load frozen model

```
frozen_path = '...'
detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
    od_graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
    with tf.compat.v1.io.gfile.GFile(frozen_path, 'rb') as fid:
        serialized_graph = fid.read()
        od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
        tf.graph_util.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
```

2/ Create a clone

```
with detection_graph.as_default():
    const_var_name_pairs = {}
    probable_variables = [op for op in detection_graph.get_operations() if op.type == "Const"]
    available_names = [op.name for op in detection_graph.get_operations()]
    for op in probable_variables:
        name = op.name
        if name+'/read' not in available_names:
            continue
        tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('{}:0'.format(name))
        with tf.compat.v1.Session() as s:
            tensor_as_numpy_array = s.run(tensor)
        var_shape = tensor.get_shape()
        # Give each variable a name that doesn't already exist in the graph
        var_name = '{}_turned_var'.format(name)
        var = tf.Variable(name=var_name, dtype=op.outputs[0].dtype, initial_value=tensor_as_numpy_array,trainable=True, shape=var_shape)
        const_var_name_pairs[name] =  var_name
```

3/ Relace frozen node by Graph Editor

```
import graph_def_editor as ge
ge_graph = ge.Graph(detection_graph.as_graph_def())
name_to_op = dict([(n.name, n) for n in ge_graph.nodes])
for const_name, var_name in const_var_name_pairs.items():
    const_op = name_to_op[const_name+'/read']
    var_reader_op = name_to_op[var_name + '/Read/ReadVariableOp']
    ge.swap_outputs(ge.sgv(const_op), ge.sgv(var_reader_op))
detection_training_graph = ge_graph.to_tf_graph()
with detection_training_graph.as_default():
    writer = tf.compat.v1.summary.FileWriter('remap', detection_training_graph )
    writer.close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my `Graph Editor` when I import the `tf.graph_def` instead of the original `tf.graph` that has Variables.

Quickly solve by fixing step 3

Sol1: Using `Graph Editor`

```
ge_graph = ge.Graph(detection_graph)
for const_name, var_name in const_var_name_pairs.items():
    const_op = ge_graph._node_name_to_node[const_name+'/read']
    var_reader_op = ge_graph._node_name_to_node[var_name+'/Read/ReadVariableOp']
    ge.swap_outputs(ge.sgv(const_op), ge.sgv(var_reader_op))
```

However, this requires disable eager execution. To work around with eager execution, you should attach the `MetaGraphDef` to `Graph Editor` as below

```
with detection_graph.as_default():
    meta_saver = tf.compat.v1.train.Saver()
    meta = meta_saver.export_meta_graph()
ge_graph = ge.Graph(detection_graph,collections=ge.graph._extract_collection_defs(meta))
```

However, this is the trickest to make the model trainable in tf2.x
Instead of using `Graph Editor` to export directly the graph, we should export ourselves. The reason is that the `Graph Editor` make the Variables data type to be `resources`. Therefore, we should export the graph as graphdef and import the variable def to the graph:

```
test_graph = tf.Graph()
with test_graph.as_default():
    tf.import_graph_def(ge_graph.to_graph_def(), name="")
    for var_name in ge_graph.variable_names:
        var = ge_graph.get_variable_by_name(var_name)
        ret = variable_pb2.VariableDef()
        ret.variable_name = var._variable_name
        ret.initial_value_name = var._initial_value_name
        ret.initializer_name = var._initializer_name
        ret.snapshot_name = var._snapshot_name
        ret.trainable = var._trainable
        ret.is_resource = True
        tf_var = tf.Variable(variable_def=ret,dtype=tf.float32)
        test_graph.add_to_collections(var.collection_names, tf_var)
```

Sol2: Manually map by Graphdef

```
with detection_graph.as_default() as graph:
    training_graph_def = remap_input_node(detection_graph.as_graph_def(),const_var_name_pairs)
    current_var = (tf.compat.v1.trainable_variables())
    assert len(current_var)>0, "no training variables"


detection_training_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_training_graph.as_default():
    tf.graph_util.import_graph_def(training_graph_def, name='')
    for var in current_var:
        ret = variable_pb2.VariableDef()
        ret.variable_name = var.name
        ret.initial_value_name = var.name[:-2] + '/Initializer/initial_value:0'
        ret.initializer_name = var.name[:-2] + '/Assign'
        ret.snapshot_name = var.name[:-2] + '/Read/ReadVariableOp:0'
        ret.trainable = True
        ret.is_resource = True
        tf_var = tf.Variable(variable_def=ret,dtype=tf.float32)
        detection_training_graph.add_to_collections({'trainable_variables', 'variables'}, tf_var)
    current_var = (tf.compat.v1.trainable_variables())
    assert len(current_var)>0, "no training variables"
```